# socket.io does not close previous connection

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

we have this socket.io serverside that on auth joins the user in the rooms he is in, but on disconnect it seems like it does not really disconnect, because on a new connect i get 2 connections, seen in screenshot. Also included is the disconnect code part.

connection part:

```
 io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    console.log("connected");
    console.log("user connected with " + socket.id);
```

disconnect part:

```
 socket.on("disconnect", function() {
  socket.removeAllListeners();
  if (socket.auth) {
    socket.groups.forEach(group => {
      console.log("left " + group.chatGroupID);
      socket.leave(group.chatGroupID);
    });
  }

  delete socket[socket.id];
  socket.disconnect(true);
  console.log(socket.disconnected);
  console.info("disconnected user (id=" + socket.id + ").");
});
```

server printout:

[image: Server log]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somehow i globbed all files in my folder sockets and thus nested my sockets which caused this weird behavior